# Simulate the "Per Graph" lifestyle in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

I'm trying to simulate the "Per Graph" lifestyle in Windsor in order to resolve my objects in the correct way. I have tried the Bound lifestyle but without any success, probably due to a lack of knowledge on the subject.
What I need is expressed in the following example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ClassA>().LifestyleBoundTo<ClassC1>(),
            //Component.For<ClassA>().LifestyleBoundTo<ClassC2>(),
            Component.For<ClassB1>().LifeStyle.Transient,
            Component.For<ClassB2>().LifeStyle.Transient,
            Component.For<ClassC1>().LifeStyle.Transient,
            Component.For<ClassC2>().LifeStyle.Transient );

        var c1 = container.Resolve<ClassC1>();
        Assert.AreSame( c1.B1.A, c1.A );

        var c2 = container.Resolve<ClassC2>();
        Assert.AreSame( c2.B2.A, c2.A );

        Assert.AreNotSame( c1.A, c2.A );
    }
}

class ClassA
{
}

class ClassB1
{
    public ClassB1( ClassA a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public ClassA A { get; set; }
}

class ClassC1
{
    public ClassC1( ClassA a, ClassB1 b1 )
    {
        A = a;
        B1 = b1;
    }

    public ClassA A { get; set; }
    public ClassB1 B1 { get; set; }
}

class ClassB2
{
    public ClassB2( ClassA a )
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public ClassA A { get; set; }
}

class ClassC2
{
    public ClassC2( ClassA a, ClassB2 b2 )
    {
        A = a;
        B2 = b2;
    }

    public ClassA A { get; set; }
    public ClassB2 B2 { get; set; }
}

}
```

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064516/dependency-injection-lifestyle-service-shared-instance-between-2-instances-of?noredirect=1#comment39052582_25064516

please let me know if you find an answer .

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it all works as expected.

Your first assert passes as expected. The second one fails as expected, since you're scoping `ClassA` per `ClassC1` and there's no instance of that class in the graph for the second resolve.

Comment: There is a way to scope ClassA also for ClassC2? In my project I have a special class that is referenced by a lot of core components. For each core component I just need one shared instance of that special class.

Comment: do your core components have a common interface they all implement?